# A "round"ed number multiplied by 0.01 results in x.y00000000000001 and not x.y?

Tags: python, odoo

The reason I'm asking this is because there is a validation in [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com/) that it's driving me crazy:

```
>>> round(1.2 / 0.01) * 0.01
1.2
>>> round(12.2 / 0.01) * 0.01
12.200000000000001
>>> round(122.2 / 0.01) * 0.01
122.2
>>> round(1222.2 / 0.01) * 0.01
1222.2
```

As you can see, the second `round` is returning an odd value.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `round`, the same happens if you just do `1220 * 0.01`. The reason is the internal representation of the floating point number.

Comment: Remember: relative-precision FP is often an approximation. For *display* round it to the desired number of decimal places in the *string representation*.

Comment: @NiklasB. You should have made that an answer.

Comment: @honk: No point, I already am far beyond the 200rep mark today :(

Comment: @NiklasB: Good for you, but the point is that this had nothing to do with `round` which all answers miss currently.

Comment: @honk: You're right, I edited the upmost answer to include this. You could have done the same, this is SO, everyone can contribute :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has in fact nothing to with `round`, you can witness the exact same problem if you just do `1220 * 0.01`:

```
>>> 1220*0.01
12.200000000000001
```

What you see here is a standard floating point issue.

You might want to read what Wikipedia has to say about [floating point accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems):

> The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and that floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many surprising situations. This is related to the finite precision with which computers generally represent numbers.

Also see:

- [Numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis)
- [Numerical stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability)

A simple example for numerical instability with floating-point: 
the numbers are finite. lets say we save 4 digits after the dot in a given computer or language.
0.0001 multiplied with 0.0001 would result something lower than 0.0001, and therefore it is impossible to save this result!
In this case if you calculate (0.0001 x 0.0001) / 0.0001 = 0.0001, this simple computer will fail in being accurate because it tries to multiply first and only afterwards to divide. In javascript, dividing with fractions leads to similar inaccuracies.

Answer (score 5):

The `float` type that you are using stores *binary* floating point numbers. Not every decimal number is exactly representable as a `float`. In particular there is no exact representation of 1.2 or 0.01, so the actual number stored in the computer will differ very slightly from the value written in the source code. This representation error can cause calculations to give slightly different results from the exact mathematical result.

It is important to be aware of the possibility of small errors whenever you use floating point arithmetic, and write your code to work well even when the values calculated are not exactly correct. For example, you should consider rounding values to a certain number of decimal places when displaying them to the user.

You could also consider using the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) type which stores *decimal* floating point numbers. If you use `decimal` then 1.2 can be stored exactly. However, working with `decimal` will reduce the performance of your code. You should only use it if exact representation of decimal numbers is important. You should also be aware that `decimal` does not mean that you'll never have any problems. For example 0.33333... has no exact representation as a `decimal`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a loss of accuracy from the division due to the way floating point numbers are stored, so you see that this identity doesn't hold

```
>>> 12.2 / 0.01 * 0.01 == 12.2
False
```

bArmageddon, has provided a bunch of links which you should read, but I believe the takeaway message is don't expect floats to give exact results unless you fully understand the limits of the representation.

**Especially don't use floats to represent amounts of money!** which is a pretty common mistake

Python also has the decimal module, which may be useful to you

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered your question and mentioned that many numbers don't have an exact binary fractional representation. If you are accustomed to working only with decimal numbers, it can seem deeply weird that a nice, "round" number like 0.01 could be a non-terminating number in some other base. In the spirit of "seeing is believing," here's a little Python program that will print out a binary representation of any number to any desired number of digits.

```
from decimal import Decimal

n = Decimal("0.01")     # the number to print the binary equivalent of
m = 1000                # maximum number of digits to print

p = -1
r = []
w = int(n)
n = abs(n) - abs(w)

while n and -p < m:
    s = Decimal(2) ** p
    if n >= s:
        r.append("1")
        n -= s
    else:
        r.append("0")
    p -= 1

print "%s.%s%s" % ("-" if w < 0 else "", bin(abs(w))[2:], 
                   "".join(r), "..." if n else "")
```